# Check if AJAX loaded form contain a submit button

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

Is there a way to check if the form that has been loaded with AJAX contain a submit button with jQuery ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
success: function(content) {
    $('#someplaceholder').html(content);
    var containsSubmitButton = $(':submit', content).length > 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but, I use a Theme, made by another person, and I cannot modify the JavaScript source files. I am looking for a solution other than the Callback into AJAX Load method

Comment: @MerianosNikos, you could then use the [`.ajaxSuccess()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) method. It allows you to register a global handler which will be executed when an AJAX request succeeds. This way you don't need to modify the code that sends the AJAX request. As far as your original question is concerned about finding whether some form contains a submit button the [`:submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit-selector/) selector should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as this

```
$("#div").load("yourpage", function() {
    if($("#div").find(":submit").length > 0) {
          console.log("yes");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a JQuery instance from your HTML content and make a query on this. 
Try:

```
        var s = "<html><body><form><input type='submit' id='submitbtn' name='submitbtn' value='Submit Button' /></form></body></html/>";
    if($(s).find("input[type='submit']").length > 0) {
        alert("true");
    } else {
        alert("false");
    }
```